# Set value of list box based on variable tkinter python 3.6

Tags: python-3.x, function, tkinter, listbox, spyder

Python 3.6, Spyder, Tkinter

Hi I have some code (a function) in an .after loop at the top of the code i get the two listbox selections at the bottom of the code i would like to switch those two values around.

Both list boxes are populated with the same data.

So say if i select #1 NZD in the first list box and #2 USD in the second then do some code calculating some stuff after I have finished calculating I would like to change to active selection of both list boxes to #1 USD and #2NZD.

So when the .after loops back to the start and it does,

```
cur1 = listbox1.get('active')
cur2 = listbox2.get('active')
```

It gets the correct switched values.

At present i tried.

```
cur1prev = cur1
cur2prev = cur2

cur1 = cur2prev
cur2 = cur1prev
listbox1.set(cur1)
listbox.set(cur2)

root.after(3000, #function for button)
```

Is there a simple way to do this, I think it has something to do with their index values.

Here is the full function, https://pastebin.com/ZrUP3VBQ

Thanks

ADDED A BASIC EXAMPLE AS REQUESTED

```
import tkinter as tk


#Make Window
root = tk.Tk()
root.geometry("612x417")
root.title("Exchange Rates")
root.resizable(0,0)
root.configure(background='lightgrey')

def printsels():
    sel1 = lb1.get('active')
    sel2 = lb2.get('active')
    print (sel1, sel2)
    lb1.select_set(sel2)
    lb2.select_set(sel1)

    root.after(3000, printsels)

lb1 = tk.Listbox(root, font="bold", height=3, width=8)
lb2 = tk.Listbox(root, font="bold", height=3, width=8)

for i in range (10):
    i = i + 1
    lb1.insert("end", i)
    lb2.insert("end", i)

lb1.pack()
lb2.pack()

btn = tk.Button(root, text="Get selections", command=printsels)
btn.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

Output just continues to be whatever i selected first as it loops.

Comment: Please don't link to code on another site. Intead, create a [mcve]. It's unclear what you want, so a _minimal_ program that shows two listboxes and just enough code to illustrated your problem will increase your chances you'll get a useful answer.

Comment: ok done as requested

Answer (score 1):

Solved.

Used at the beginning of the loop.

```
index1 = listbox1.get(0, "end").index(cur1)
index2 = listbox2.get(0, "end").index(cur2)
```

used at the end of the loop.

```
listbox1.activate(index2)
listbox2.activate(index1)
```

Final code is

```
def results():
    if running:
        global usraccbal
        cur1 = listbox1.get('active')
        cur2 = listbox2.get('active')

        index1 = listbox1.get(0, "end").index(cur1)
        index2 = listbox2.get(0, "end").index(cur2)

        print (index1,index2)

        frmcur_text.set(cur1)
        tocur_text.set(cur2)

        t = datetime.utcnow()  
        lbldatetime_text.set(t)


#get usr input of text box for amount to trade    this is trade 1
        usraccbal = Decimal (cnvrtamt.get())


#Get rates and assign  their values to variables rate1contents and rate2contents then print

        var1 = getrates(cur1, cur2)
        var2 = (var1[0])
        var3 = (var1[1])
        rate1contents = Decimal (var2)
        rate2contents = Decimal (var3)
        #print the exrates
        print ('currency1',cur1,' to currency2', cur2, '=',rate1contents)
        print ('currency2',cur2,' to currency1', cur1, '=',rate2contents)

#Do trade number 1 giving result as a variable cnvrt
        #Do trade number 1 as a variable 
        c = newconvert(usraccbal, rate1contents)
        #unpack values from trade1 variable for use in other calculations
        newcnvrt = Decimal (c[0])
        prevusraccbal = Decimal (c[1])
        #make variable calle cnvrt with result of newconvert function
        cnvrt = newcnvrt
        #Print the result of trade 1 and the previous accbal/amount converted
        print ('#1 Trade =',cur2, 'newaccbal', newcnvrt,'previous account balance =', prevusraccbal,)

#Update tk labels for result of converted amount and which currency we converted to
        lblconvertedamtval_text.set(newcnvrt)
        lblconvertedcur_text.set(cur2)
#Update tk labels for previous currency data        
        lblprevcur_text.set(cur1)
        lblprevcuramt_text.set(prevusraccbal)
#set user account balance again
        usraccbal = newcnvrt
        cnvrtamt.set(usraccbal)
        #Attempt to trade back to cur1
        #Store old country codes
        cur1prev = cur1
        cur2prev = cur2
#       Store previous amount that was converted
        cnvrtamtprev = Decimal (prevusraccbal)
#Store old conversion result    
        cnvrtresultprev = Decimal (newcnvrt)
#Do trade back
        cur1 = cur2prev
        cur2 = cur1prev
        listbox1.activate(index2)
        listbox2.activate(index1)
        print ('new cur1 =', cur1, 'new cur2 =',cur2)


        root.after(3000,results)
```